# Can a CSS class provide introductory and/or closing text?

Tags: css

I have a CSS class that I use to provide an executive summary:

```
/*Executive summary.*/
.exec-summ {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

I would like it to automatically include the initial text 'SUMMARY: ' in any paragraph with class='exec-summ'. I have a vague memory that this can be done in CSS but I can't find any relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. See below.

```css
/*Executive summary.*/
.exec-summ {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.exec-summ::before,
.exec-summ:before {
  content: 'Summary: ';
}
```

```html
<div class="exec-summ">Meow</div>
```

Reference: [before pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

Comment: It seems that :before is CSS2 and ::before is CSS3, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: @Argent Yip. I updated my answer to only use `::before`. I believe he wanted to be sarcastic or something?

Comment: @SVSchmidt I find it informative that both :before and ::before work. I'd put your answer back to its original form.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want

```
.exec-summ::before {
     content: 'SUMMARY:';
}
```

```css
.exec-summ {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
.exec-summ::before {
     content: 'SUMMARY:';
     margin-right: 4px;
     opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div class=exec-summ>The summary</div>
```